# Deploy - React show me "Cannot Get" when I refresh my page

Tags: reactjs, react-router, sequelize.js, react-router-dom

I deployed my react-app with server and database : https://www.mon-gouvernement.fr/

I use `axios` to get and post my data into my database.
I use `sequelize` to manage my database.

**App.js**

```
<BrowserRouter>
        {/* appBar position */}
        <ResponsiveAppBar />

        <Container component="main" maxWidth="md">
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/a-propos" element={<About />} />
            <Route path="/creer-son-gouvernement" element={<CreateGovernment />} />
            <Route path="/gouvernement-galerie" element={<GovernmentWall />} />
            <Route path="/gouvernement/:id" element={<GovernmentId />} />
            <Route path="*" element={<Error404 />} />
          </Routes>
        </Container>
        <Footer />
      </BrowserRouter>
```

**Server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

const db = require('./models');


const governmentCreateRouter = require('./routes/GovernmentCreate');
app.use("/governmentCreate", governmentCreateRouter);


db.sequelize.sync().then(() => {
    app.listen();
});
```

**gouvernement-galerie.js**

```
useEffect(() => {

        axios.get(`https://www.mon-gouvernement.fr/GovernmentCreate`)
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res.data);

                setGovernmentList(res.data);

            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    }, []);
```

Everything works perfectly until I try to refresh my page `gouvernement-galerie.js`. When I did it my page show me : `Cannot GET /gouvernement-galerie`.

After longs searching on StackOverFlow, I discovered that if I add lines below into my `.htaccess`, that will solve my issu.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

But unfortunautly, that change nothing. Yes, my page stop to show me Cannot Get, but `axios.get()` return nothing and my page stay empty.

Could you help my to solve this problem ?

Comment: looks like your routes are not properly setup. also, https://www.mon-gouvernement.fr/GovernmentCreate returns a Component but from your web-app console errors i could see that you are trying to use a map function on the html doc.
`TypeError: t.map is not a function
    at GovernmentWall.js:31:29
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at GovernmentWall.js:29:37`

Comment: But that the point. If I don't add the piece of code in my `.htaccess` everything work until I refresh.
I'm also surprise to see what return my `console.log(res.data)` when the piece à code is present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, **I solve my problem**.

I put my front-end files `build` on my server side and I add some code on my **server.js**

[image]

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
const path = require('path');

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

const db = require('./models');


//************************************************
// ROUTES
//************************************************
const governmentCreateRouter = require('./routes/GovernmentCreate');
app.use("/governmentCreate", governmentCreateRouter);


app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));
app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});


//************************************************
// CONNECTION TO DATABASE
//************************************************
db.sequelize.sync().then(() => {
    app.listen();
});
```

I also add into my **package.json** this line

```
"homepage": "https://www.mon-gouvernement.fr/",
```